# How can I use firebase in a framework I'm creating?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, frameworks

I am creating a framework which will do some analytic related stuff. I am wondering if I use `firebase` as my database how to include it in the framework.

On the same note, will having `firebase` in my framework cause issues if the app using my framework is also using `firebase`?

I've read that frameworks should not include other frameworks, but I'm clueless how other frameworks are uploading things to their databases then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue while developing a Cocoapod-based framework that involved another dependency.

```
s.dependency 'Alamofire'
```

Simply add this line to the `podspec` and it will include the other framework as well.

> I've read that frameworks should not include other frameworks, but I'm clueless how other frameworks are uploading things to their databases then.

Yeah, that's the general approach. With Cocoapods, your framework won't include the dependency, it will simply install it as another framework. If it is already installed then it won't do anything.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for your help. Literally as you answered this I was reading this https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html and I was coming back to this question to include "Should I use a podspec" Thank you for confirming this.